# itextsharp 5.5.5 textcolor property is removed

Tags: c#, pdf, itext

I have updated my itextsharp for 4.x.x to 5.5.5 (latest version)
However the following line will give an error:

```
Font heading1 = new Font(bfTimes, 16, Font.BOLD, Color.BLACK);
```

Error: The name'Color' does not exist in the current context

itextsharp.text.font.**color** is removed from the new version.

How do I set the color in the new itextsharp version?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set the color like this:

```
var color = new BaseColor(255, 0, 0); //or BaseColor.RED
var font = FontFactory.GetFont(bfTimes, 16, Font.BOLD, color);
```

Comment: Thank you, 
I already used the BaseColor property and that works fine.

Answer (score 1):

I had to use `BaseColor` instead.